# consecutive use of fixed_quad error

Tags: python, scipy

I am very new to Python and trying to do consecutive integrals without a problem when I use quad, but got stuck when I swap to fixed_quad, like in the following test example:

```
def test(z,r):
  return r*z**2 + 5
def inttest(r):
  return fixed_quad(test, 10*r, 100, args=(r,))[0]
def test2(r, t):
  return inttest(r)*(2*t+3)
def inttest2(t):
  return fixed_quad(test2, 3, 5, args = (t,), n=5)[0]
print inttest2(3)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\tt11.py", line 132, in <module>
    print inttest2(3)
  File "C:\Python27\tt11.py", line 129, in inttest2
    return fixed_quad(test2, 3, 5, args = (t,), n=5)[0]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadrature.py", line 58, in fixed_quad
    return (b-a)/2.0*sum(w*func(y,*args),0), None
  File "C:\Python27\tt11.py", line 124, in test2
    return inttest(r)*(2*t+3)
  File "C:\Python27\tt11.py", line 119, in inttest
    return fixed_quad(test, 10*r, 100, args=(r,))[0]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadrature.py", line 54, in fixed_quad
    if ainf or binf:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or   a.all()
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `test2` has two variables and you just integrate over one of them while you didn't determine the other.

Comment: @Dalek, that is not the case, see `args = (t,)`? The problem is due to `test2()` being not able to take `np.array` as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one word, your code is not working because `test2` can not take `np.array` as input.

The relevant code in `fixed_quad` is quite short:

```
def fixed_quad(func,a,b,args=(),n=5):
    [x,w] = p_roots(n)
    x = real(x)
    ainf, binf = map(isinf,(a,b))
    if ainf or binf:
         raise ValueError("Gaussian quadrature is only available for "
                 "finite limits.")
    y = (b-a)*(x+1)/2.0 + a
    return (b-a)/2.0*sum(w*func(y,*args),0), None
```

and the docstring indicates:

```
Parameters
----------
func : callable
    A Python function or method to integrate (must accept vector inputs).
```

`y` is going to be `np.array` of size `(n, )`. Therefore if your `test2` can't take `np.array` as input `func(y,*args)` will rise error.

For these reasons, if we supply `n=1`, it will work (but of course is useless):

```
def inttest2(t):
  return si.fixed_quad(test2, 3, 5, args = (t,), n=1)[0]
print inttest2(3) 
#22469400.0
```

The solution, is to allow `test2` to take `np.array` as import of `r`:

```
def test2(r, t):
    return np.array(map(inttest, np.array(r)))*(2*t+3)
def inttest2(t):
    return fixed_quad(test2, 3, 5, args = (t,), n=5)[0]
print inttest2(3)
#22276200.0
```